# how to relocate grub2 & windowsboot manager from HDD to SSD?

Tags: linux, windows

After formatting previously installed windows 10 partition then I installed windows 10 to SSD leaving my kali linux remains on my HDD only
but my windows 10 bootmanager and grub2 both are on HDD partition (shown in the image **/dev/sda2** it should be **/dev/nvme0n1p1** )
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `update-grub` to update your `grub.cfg`?

Comment: yes I did,it's showing windows boot manager on */dev/sda2*

Comment: `Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`